# Find dialog box hidden in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Find/Replace dialog box is not visible during search.

After doing frequent find/replace in SQL Server 2008 R2 the dialog box is hidden now, I am able to find the text but the dialog box is not being shown.

Can anyone here tell me how can i make the dialog box to be visible ?

Thanks :-

Karan #ftg

Comment: Do you have two screens? And, did you try restarting the SSMS?

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

Comment: @thepirat000 yes I meant that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Press <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> to bring the search dialog that is hidden.

Press the left <kbd>ALT</kbd> followed by the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (not at the same time) and that will probably bring up the window menu.

Press the <kbd>M</kbd> to select "**m**ove" and now you can probably move the window to a visible position with the arrow keys or the mouse.

[image]